# Who first noticed the duality for finite groups?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ho.history-overview

A.A.Kirillov in section 12.3 of his ["Elements of the Theory of Representations"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642662454) writes that the first "symmetric" duality theory for non-commutative groups was the theory for finite groups. In short what he writes can be explained as follows: the operation $G\mapsto{\mathbb C}_G$ that assigns to each finite group $G$ its group algebra ${\mathbb C}_G$ over ${\mathbb C}$, embeds the category of all finite groups into the category of finite dimensional Hopf algebras, so that the Pontryagin duality functor $G\mapsto\widehat{G}$ (for Abelian finite groups) turns into the operation $H\mapsto H^{*}$ of taking the dual vector space (which is a duality functor in the category of finite dimensional Hopf algebras).

This observation is used as a key example in different modern duality theories. I wonder

> who first noticed this?

Kirillov does not give the name.
[image: Duality for finite groups.]

Comment: Dear Sergei, I have no answer (sorry :) but am very interested in the forthcoming feedbacks (+1)